# How To Display Only One Number After Point Without RoundUp

Tags: c#

Here I trying to display only one number after decimal without roundup the number in C# asp.net mvc.
Eg 
1.234 - 1.2
1.899 - 1.8
Any help will be heartly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: And what have you tried so far to solve this problem? What issue you are facing with whatever you have tried so far? Considered converting number to string and using string operations to get what you want?

Comment: actually i have used Math.Round function but i think that does not give the answer as per required @ChetanRanpariya